# How to pass a Core Data fetched results to a NavigationLink destination as a property of the destination View without returning nil?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm learning how to integrate Core Data with SwiftUI and so I'm building a Login/SignUp View which has a destination leading to a Content View.

I'm trying to create a new User object in my SignUp view, and when the user taps on the SIGN UP button, to execute a Core Data fetch request that will fetch that user in order to display their details in the Content View.

The problem I'm having is that destination gets executed immediately once the SignUp View is displayed, and that triggers the Nil Coalescent in my getDestination function, which adds a new User object to the context via User(context: moc) since the fetch doesn't get executed since the object has yet to be created.

How do I avoid the execution of the nil coalescent when the Sign Up View is displayed and also when I tap the Sign Up button?

```
NavigationLink(
        destination: getDestination(from: admin),
        isActive: self.$isSignUpValid){
        Text("Sign Up")
            .onTapGesture {
                createUserObject(company: self.company, name: self.name, username: self.username, password: self.password, photo: self.inputImage, admin: self.admin)
                selectedUser = fetchUserDetails(withUser: username)
                self.selectedImageArray = imagesFromCoreData(object: selectedUser!.photo!)!
                isSignUpValid = true
            }
    }
    
//Sets appropariate destination based on value of Admin property.
func getDestination(from adminValue: Bool) -> AnyView {
    
    if adminValue == false {
        return AnyView(ContentView(selectedUser: self.selectedUser ?? User(context: moc), selectedImageArray: self.selectedImageArray))
    }
    else {
        return AnyView(AdminView(selectedUser: self.selectedUser ?? User(context: moc), selectedImageArray: self.selectedImageArray))
    }
}



func createUserObject(company: String, name: String, username: String, password: String, photo: UIImage?, admin: Bool){
    
    //Produces a Data object from an Array of Images.
    func coreDataObjectFromImages(image: UIImage) -> Data? {
        let dataArray = NSMutableArray()
        
        if let data = image.pngData() {
            dataArray.add(data)
        }
        return try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dataArray, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    }
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    let newUser = User(context: context)
    newUser.id = UUID()
    newUser.admin = admin
    newUser.company = company
    newUser.name = name
    newUser.username = username
    newUser.password = password
    newUser.photo = coreDataObjectFromImages(image: (photo ?? UIImage(systemName:"person.circle")!))
    
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("New User Created")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func fetchUserDetails(withUser user: String) -> User? {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username == %@", user)
    
    do {
        let fetchUser = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return fetchUser.first
    } catch let fetchError {
        print("Failed to fetch: \(fetchError)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: We can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The managed object can always be nil, so you will have to handle that in your code. Why not wait to create the user in the next view? Then you could simply pass the credentials and go from there.

Comment: Thanks pal, you actually did answer my question.